# MySQL: Why are these two wrong? (Invalid use of group function, selected nothing after using having())

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having-clause

*Credit:Leetcode_1076.Project Employees II*
Here is the sample table
Project table:

```
 project_id  | employee_id 

 1           | 1           
 1           | 2           
 1           | 3           
 2           | 1           
 2           | 4
```

(project_id, employee_id) is the primary key of this table.

I have tried several methods and managed to find the right one by using dense_rank(); however, I still don't understand why these two syntaxes are wrong to select project_id with the largest number of employees:

**1.Return null: {"headers": ["project_id", "n"], "values": []}**

```
select project_id, count(*) as n
from project
group by project_id
having max(n)
```

- I was expecting it to return {"headers": ["project_id", "n"], "values": [1,3]}.

**2. Error: Invalid use of group function**

```
SELECT project_id, max(count(*)) as n
from project 
group by project_id
```

Really appreciate it if anyone can help me out!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one common issue with both of your approaches, and that is, you are attempting to access aggregated result in the SQL at same level. You can not have nested aggregate functions (Eg. max(count(1)) in SQL.

Your SQL should be as follows -

```
select t.project_id, max(t.n) from (select project_id, count(*) as n
from project
group by project_id) t;
```

SQLFiddle demonstration -
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c9b18/4

Answer (score 0):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select project_id, count(*) as n
from project
group by project_id
order by n desc
limit 1;
```

If you want to handle ties, then use window functions:

```
select p.*
from (select project_id, count(*) as n,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from project
      group by project_id
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon! But this table is a sample table. There may have projects that have the same largest number of employees on the whole table.